# Nodejs streaming a continuously growing text file using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application i am using angularjs on Nodejs. I want to read a file which is continuously growing line by line. The frequency of adding new lines is very high, lets say ~100 lines per seconds where line size is approximate 200 characters.

I want to know what would be the best possible way to do this with minimum lag. Currently I am trying this by making an api and call from scripts below but this is not working as expected. I think there must be better way to do this for such high frequently changing file.

I want to read file line by line and process for dashboard display. Please suggest best possible approach, with working example if possible.

Many thanks in advance.

```
    // app.js
    app.post('/readTfile',function (req,res) {
    console.log('i recievied a get request in app.js = /readTfile');    
    var fullfilename = req.body.filepath+"\\"+req.body.filename;
    var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(fullfilename);

    readStream.pipe(res);

        res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + fullfilename
        }); 
    });
```

And calling this in html.

```
var FileName = "MyFile.xml"
var obj = {"filepath" : 'D:\\myapp\\public', "filename" : FileName};

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/readfile",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(obj),
      success: function(res){
            $scope.readfiledata = res;
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(errorThrown);
      } 
    });
```

Comment: You could try using websockets with socket.io. I think that might work better. Not positive.

Comment: I am new to angularjs. would you please refer me some link where i can get some working example.

Comment: Oh yeah sure. Do you need help? It's not related to angular. It's a node thing. A way of having the server tell the client side when things have changed.

Comment: Yes @Koval. I desperately need help. I have been searching but couldn't find any example. please refer me some link/plnkr for working example.

Comment: So I just googled socket.io tutorial and a chat app came up. It will give an idea of how to use it.

Comment: I have a feeling my idea will work worse honestly. A lot of it depends on the data you are sending. Is it just the new lines that were added?

Comment: I found "tailing-stream" node module which seems to be contrast to the standard fs.createReadStream.Please share your opnion.

Comment: I just read through what it does and it should be finebfor reading the data, however I don't know if that solvesvyour problem. I don't think it will do anything with getting the data to the client side, which is where the challenge comes imo. Getting a high update rate with so much data.